# not recieving session variable

Tags: php, html, session, authentication

I am making a login system for a mini project for school. I finished the register part already, but now I have to do the login part. my problem is that I can't seem to access the session variable on the other page. it is not returning anything on the other page. I would love to know what I'm doing wrong here.

NOTE: if theyre logged in, im sending them back to the register page. this is just a test.

login.php:

```
<?php
 session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$servername = "localhost";
$username  = "root";
$password  = "";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, "vbproject");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); 
}

$username = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
$password = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["wachtwoord"]);
$query = "SELECT `userID` FROM `users` where username='$username' and password='$password'";

if ($result = $conn->query($query)) 
{

  if($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
  {
      $_SESSION["ID"] = $row["userID"];
      $_SESSION["name"] = $row["username"];
      header("Location: ../web/register.php");

  }

  $result->close();
 }
}
?>
```

register.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['ID'])){
        echo "You are logged in";

    }
    ?>
</body>
```

edit :

```
 `<?php 
     session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
    echo $_SESSION['name'];

   }
   ?>`
```

Comment: you're not using session_start() on page register.php?

Comment: As @lovelace mentioned, you need session_start() within your register.php at the start of the page otherwise $_SESSION will never be able to be accessed.

Comment: @lovelace haha yes that was the problem, thank you! now im trying to echo out the variable name. but its not giving me a result? i updated my code for you to see.

Comment: try to debug with setting a dummy $_SESSION variable (e.g. $_SESSION['dummy'] = 'dummy'; and see if you can echo it, if so, the problem is in the data retrieval from the database.

Comment: Passwords should ***NEVER*** be stored in plain text form. They should ***ALWAYS*** be hashed. As for the problem with the sessions, try running the query direct against the database via PHPMyAdmin to confirm that it actually returns what you expect it to return